# Can we access xml schema (xsd) through url?

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, xsd

I have deployed a war file (SCALAServices.war) on tomcat server. The war contains HumanActivitySchema.xsd file inside /WebContent/WEB-INF/resources folder. How can I access this xsd directly from browser through URL? What changes am I suppose to do for this?

I don't have much idea about web projects. So please help me in this.